# Cropping image let the picture rotate left

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, crop

I'm developing an app to crop images.
I'm using the following code to call the method of cropping:

```
UIImage* croppedImage = [self imageCrop:imageView toRect:CGRectMake(10.0, 50.0, 320, 100)];
```

and here is the code of the method:

```
{
    //create a context to do our clipping in
    CGRect newRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, imageViewToCrop.transform);
    UIImage *imageToCrop = imageViewToCrop.image;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newRect.size);
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //create a rect with the size we want to crop the image to
    //the X and Y here are zero so we start at the beginning of our
    //newly created context
    CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextClipToRect( currentContext, clippedRect);

    //draw the image to our clipped context using our offset rect
    CGContextDrawImage(currentContext, newRect, imageToCrop.CGImage);

    //pull the image from our cropped context
    UIImage *cropped = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //pop the context to get back to the default
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return cropped;
}
```

The problem is when I set this image to UIImageView, I found the returned image is rotated left. And I can't get it Rotated Up.
Any one could know the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David wrote the problem is likely that you are not preserving **imageOrientation** property. Also the problem with your code is that you do not preserve **scale** property.
Try creating your cropped image like this:

```
CGImageRef croppedRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(currentContext);
UIImage* cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedRef scale:imageToCrop.scale orientation:imageToCrop.imageOrientation];
CGImageRelease(croppedRef);
```

Comment: Hi, when I do this, my rotation is still off. Can you think of a reason using imageOrientation does not work properly?

Answer (score 2):

Uiimage have an **imageOrientation** property that in some cases indicated the way the system should display the bits of the image. Try logging that value and see. If its as I suspect then you may need to adjust your crop algorithm, create a CGImage first, then use the UIImage method to make a UIImage from it that has an orientation parameter.